# WebDriver / Read elements into variables and re-use them

Tags: selenium

I have a big issue With `Webdriver` (Selenium 2).

In my test code, I find all the elements in the beginning of my test, and do some actions on them (like `click`(), checking attributes, etc.). My problem is that my page is refreshed and re-load my elements, and Webdriver don't know to recognize the elements again.

I know that I can find my elements again, but in some functions I don't know my XPath/ids, and I get just the WebElements, not XPath/IDs.

Am I right in saying that it's no possible to read elements into variables and re-use them?

Answer (score 5):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("xyz"));
```

The above line will store the element object in the `element` variable. You can certainly pass this element to other functions to make use of it over there.

We generally follow the [**page object** design pattern](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/encouraged/page_object_models/) where we create all objects of a page as members of a class and instantiate them at once. This way we can use them anywhere in our project. For example all objects in the login page will be created as public static variables in a class called `LoginPage`. The constructor of `LoginPage` class will find elements and store them.

Next time anywhere you want to access an object of `LoginPage`, we access them as below (assuming that you have created elements `userName` and `submit`)...

```
LoginPage.userName.sendKeys("buddha");
LoginPage.submit.click();
```

However, as Robbie mentioned there is a chance for these objects to become inaccessible using the previously created object after a page refresh. You can use the below modified approach for ensuring these objects are always found.

Instead of creating the objects as a **member variable**, create a **get method** for each object that you may need to use.

```
class LoginPage
{
    public static WebElement getUserName()
    {
         return driver.findElement(By.id("xyz"));
    }
}
```

Once `LoginPage` is defined that way, next time you want to use `userName`, you can use the below syntax. This way you don't have to give locators to the functions that need to use these objects.

```
LoginPage.getUserName().sendKeys("buddha");
```

By using this approach, you can ensure that the objects are always accessible.

Answer (score 2):

Buddha is incorrect in the following statement:

> You can reuse it any number of times, however, it only works as long as the id doesn't change.

As you have correctly observed, if the page reloads, then elements become stale, even if the original object is still displayed on screen. In fact, refreshing of HTML via AJAX calls can also make objects stale even if the URL has not changed.

This is how Selenium works, and you have to understand this when deciding how to implement a test framework.

You can store elements, reuse them and pass them to functions, but understand when they will become stale and need to be refound.

In my current project, I have a very AJAX heavy application in which objects are continually becoming stale, so have extended WebElement to find and store it's HTML Id when constructed, then refinds by id if a stale element exception occurs and re performs the method that failed. However, this was achieved using Ruby and very specific to my application as I know every object has a unique HTML Id. I do not believe this approach would work for most applications under test.

I would also question whether storing elements in public static variables populated on construction, is actually following the Page Object pattern. I have never seen it implemented this way before, and can see lots of potential pitfalls. Lazy instantiation may be a better approach when following the Page Object pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. We have never faced the issue of objects becoming stale, may be that is because we didn't work with pages refreshing too frequently.