# Changing the find by criteria inside a method with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I was looking for answer for a while but I'm helpless for now on.
I'm developing project with Selenium for automation for our web application with the usage of Page object pattern.
I've notice some places where maybe I could improve my framework for changes with GUI on my app. Here is the thing that I've got some main menu which has submenus for each record in this main menu ( sub menu is displayed after record is hovered or clicked)
My app is customized very much for client requests, and I want to ensure my framework to be as flexible as it can be when wanting to veryfing on other enviornment configuration. The very most difference is with the order of elements in main menu and sub menus, and alignment of element to corresponding sub menus.
I'm currently iterating through elements in menu and based on name of the element I'm assigning this element to corresponding WebElement, but when I want to assign elements in submenus it works correctly but I'm unable to click this element.
I was looking for some answers with Java not passing reference to a method but haven't found some solution/workaround
I will present you this in code:
I use Cucumber for defining test methods

```
public void goToStudentDatA(){
    mainPage = new MainPage(base.driver)
    mainPage.NavigateToPage(mainPage.StudentData, Common.Category.Informations
}
```

StudentaData is an WebElement in MainPage navigating to a form where I want to go
navigateToPage is an method which based on Common.Category.Informations hovers on specific element so subMenu can be shown

```
public void NavigateToPage(WebElement page, Common.Category category)
{
    switch(category)
    {
        case Informations:
            this.DisplayHiddenList(this.driver,this.Informations);
            break;
    }
    page.click();
}
```

In the displayHiddenList I have a conditions which find elements in submenu Informations and then assign correct element based on name of element from submenu (one record of menu stores few elements which are present on submenu)
so after DisplayHiddenList, my element mainPage.StudentData is pointing to webElement with correct XPath (and it is) but in method NavigateToPage, page object is still referencing on nothing (it is  WebElement so its find method show that in debug: Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'by id or name "Student_Data"' , so obviously it cannot be found on the page.
Do you have any suggest how to change 'page' instance so it will refreshed? page is an intance passed of MainPage.StudentData (WebElement) passed from method GoToStudentData()

I know Java is passing non-primitive variable by value, but I think there is some workaround?
Main reason is to eliminate @FindBy annotation in MainPage class, as MainPage represents navigationbar, mainmenu.

Edit 1: displayHiddenList

```
public void displayHiddenList(WebDriver driver, WebElement 
listToDisplay)
{
//buildperform is hovering menu so submenu is visible
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(listToDisplay).build().perform();

    //Functionality for adding elements based on their hierarchy in DOM 
    //relatively to passed element listToDisplay
    WebElement menuDiv = 
 listToDisplay.findElement(By.ByXPath.xpath("following-sibling::div"));
    List<WebElement> listToDisplayMenu = 
menuDiv.findElements(By.ByClassName.className("rmLink"));
    //DisplayMenuList lftMenuListItem;
    for (WebElement element : listToDisplayMenu)
    {
        LeftMenuList category = 
        LeftMenuList.valueOf(listToDisplay.getText().replace(" ", "_"));
        switch (category)
        {
            case Student:
                StudentList stdListItem = 
                StudentList.valueOf(element.getText().replace(" ", 
                "_").replace("/","_"));
                switch (stdListItem)
                {
                    case Data:                            
                        Student_Data = element;
                        //!! If i would click here Student_Data or element it 
                        //is ok so field is updated but page variable in 
                        //NavigateToPage method is not referencing to this 
                        //field
                        break;
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Edit2: Temporary Solution
I made a workaround, instead of calling class field in test method, I'm passing enum type with name of element I want to navigate, then in NavigateToPage method I'm searching for the same element and if it is found then it is clicked.

But still I wish to know answer to my question, is there some workaround to do similiraly like in C#, where passing by reference exists.
I'm passing object which points to private field, after private field for this instance is changed, object which was passed does not change it's state.

EDIT3 FINISH
The problem was I have been incorrectly using references to instances of classes, I have been passing reference but then my private field element has been updated so it pointed to another address, therefore the variable was still pointing on the same element. I used solution in Edit2# to overcome this, and for me it is good enough. Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you post a link to the page? My guess is that you can pass in a string (or strings) that represents the navigation levels in the menus and handle it that way. You can find the elements on the fly by their contained text (labels) instead of prelocating their elements.

Comment: I think I'm doing what you mean, I firstly find all elements which are under one record of menu by some class name, after it I'm veryfing text of each element and based on that I'm assigning this element to appriopate field in class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question, you are not able to click on the sub menus but you can locate them? Please provide some sample HTML.

You can try using:

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
```

Before you click on the element. Alternatively, HTML dropdowns with "option" tags are not difficult to deal with but each dropdown varies site per site.

Another guess would be the element is becoming stale. Element attributes can change when menus are navigated (i.e. open or disabled attributes), and in some cases selenium can no longer handle these elements unless they are located again.

Here is a [post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12029/how-do-i-work-with-dropdowns-in-selenium-webdriver) that may help you, please post your HTML.

```
WebElement mySelectElm = driver.findElement(By.id("mySelectID")); 
Select mySelect= new Select(mySelectElm);
selMySelect.selectByVisibleText("Option");
```

Comment: I have field StudentData which I'm calling from goToStudentData() test method and inside NavigateToPage I'm trying to click it, but before this click is fired I'm assignig  element to this field (StudentData), based on some criteria, if I would call this element (this.StudentData.click()) excplicitly after assigning is done it would be ok (but I want to method NavigateToPage be smart and click element which is passed to method), but instead this passed element is not referencing to class field (StudentData). The problem here is I want to get rid of FindBy annotation in MainPage class

Comment: I edited post to show how Student_Data is changed, if text of finded element has text 'Data' then it assigns founded element to Student_Data field, as comment stait, if I in in displayHiddenList method called Student_data.click or element.click() then element is properly clicked.

Comment: Try creating a separate class that has a WebElement data field and getMyElement() method, lets say called button.java. Then you can call button element = new button(); and then call button.getMyElement() all within your NavigateToPage method. This will give you the same ability but without passing it as method parameter, should also protect against staleelementreferences, see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866836/webdriver-read-elements-into-variables-and-re-use-them